# VSCode integrated terminal doesn't use Conda environment to execute python files

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code

[Mac OS] Up until yesterday, my python files were executing with whatever environment I had activated. After that, I explored python debugging and how it could be used with the Conda environment. It worked like a charm.

Today, I got a notification in VSC saying something along the lines of "python.PythonPath in settings.json ... default...". Because I was in a hurry, I didn't pay attention to it. Now, when I activate conda environment X, it shows up in the terminal that X is activated, when I use "conda list" it lists the correct modules installed in X, and in VSC's status bar, it shows that I am using X too.

Unfortunately, when I go running the python code, it simply uses "python - u ", and that does not happen to be X.

Could someone please tell me what's wrong? If there's some information that I haven't provided, please feel free to let me know about it and I'll update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the VSCode works like the first picture and you want it can run in the terminal like the second picture?

[image]

[image]

The first picture was running by `Code Runner`, the second picture was running by `Python Extension`. You can choose it like this:

[image]

If I am misunderstanding your problem, please point it out and provide the related info.

Comment: @vikram look forward to your response.

Comment: @vikram I thought I misunderstood your problem, but it weird, hope you can respond to this answer.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I just tried this and by selecting "Run Python File in Terminal" the code was executed using the Conda environment. However, previously, I would only press 'control + R' and the code would be executed using the appropriate environment. Do you know how I can make it that way again? In any case, I'm really glad for your response, because I was feeling low the whole day because this stuff wasn't working as expected, lol.

Comment: @vikram You can custom the shortcut, but I was a little confused about your shortcut: Ctrl+R. Because the default shortcut of Code Runner was: Ctrl_Alt+N, F5 was the default shortcut of Debugging, and there is no shortcut of Run Python File in Terminal. Anyway, you can custom the shortcut to anyone you like. File --> Preferences --> Keyboard Shortcuts to open the shortcut panel.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify settings.json to use the specific conda environment python interpreter. Or you can set the interpreter manually. \

*Writing settings.json*: 
add the line in **settings.json** :

```
"python.pythonPath": "/home/python36/python", // the path of python 
// interpreter in your desired conda environment.
```

Or In the editor to the bottom left corner, you should see something like below
[image: Editor] 
Click it, you should see a prompt opening above, like
[image] 
Select the interpreter and you're good to go.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Unfortunately, everything is exactly the way you have mentioned already. In the bottom I can see that the interpreter being used is "('ML' : conda)" (which is the correct conda environment), and I have even specified the correct path to the python executable (of the conda environment) in settings.json. Despite that, the code runs with the default Python interpreter (I have tried changing the default to be 'ML': conda too, but it did not work). @Steven's answer tells me that CodeRunner is taking priority over Python extension when I try to run the code. Any fixes?